# Google OAuth2 fails for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I did everything my google manual for OAuth2.
Html:

```
<div id="my-signin2"></div>
```

JS:

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
        alert("uraaa");
        console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
    }

    function onFailure(error) {
        alert("uff");

        console.log(error);
    }

    function renderButton() {
        gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
            'width': 100,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': false,
            'theme': 'light',
            'onsuccess': onSuccess,
            'onfailure': onFailure
        });
    }

</script>
```

It works well for Chrome and FireFox. And no authorization happens in Internet Explorer 11.

How to fix it?